# Player-turn based Dice game (having trouble with loops)

Tags: c#, loops, dice

Background; I'm trying to create a dice game for multi-players where you can choose how many players, sides on the die and dice's themselves you want in the game. And players each take a turn rolling n amount of dices and per each roll the score gets appended to the player classes playerScore property. Once a player reaches X amount of points, player is declared a winner.

Problem; The below code is part of the "Game" class. When I compile the code, the game does what I expect for the most part; it rolls 5 dices each turn per player and appends the points to said player, but once the player reaches 100 points, the player is declared a winner, but the die's are rolled again for another player, despite the fact that the while loop is invalidated. The way i see it, the problem is with the for loop, but I have no idea how to fix this, i tried "break" but it only breaks from the if statement.

My program has 3 classes; Die, Player, Game. If you need more information or screen shots. I can provide them.

[image]

P.S. If you think this code could be improved, please comment, I'd be glad to hear it out.

Comment: *" i tried "break" but it only breaks from the if statement"* - that's not true, it breaks from the `for` loop. The problem is your logic for the check, it does not happen when you increment the value, it happens in the next iteration of the `while` loop

Comment: I suggest to use a debugger and step through your code while watching the values of the player properties. You'll soon find out where your logic goes wrong (if a player reaches `maxPoints`, you simply go to the next player and check if _this_ player already won in the last round).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if statements are messing with your flow. Why?

```
if (gameEnded || playerArray[i].PlayerScore >= maxPoints)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, Player '{0}' has won by reaching {1} points.",playerArray[i].PlayerName, playerArray[i].PlayerScore);
   gameEnded = true;
   break;
} 
else if (!gameEnded )
{
    playerArray[i].PlayerScore += rollAllDice();
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}': {1}", playerArray[i].PlayerName, playerArray[i].PlayerScore);
}
```

Here, you're checking if the current player has reached the final score. If so, you break you for loop and set gameEnded = true, breaking the while loop as well. But this checks the score of the current player; it doesn't check if the current player has reached the score. This way, you will only discover if Player A won the game on the next round, not the current.

---

This way, as soon as a player reaches the score, the game ends:

```
public void StartGame(int maxPoints)
{
    playerArray[0].PlayerTurn = true; // Not sure why you're doing this, so I'm gonna leave this here

    Player winner = null;

    while (!gameEnded)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.Length; i++)
        {            
            Player currentPlayer = playerArray[i];

            currentPlayer.PlayerScore += rollAllDice();
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}': {1}", currentPlayer.PlayerName, currentPlayer.PlayerScore);

            if (currentPlayer.PlayerScore >= maxPoints) 
            {
                winner = currentPlayer;
                gameEnded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, Player '{0}' has won by reaching {1} points.", winner.PlayerName, winner.PlayerScore);
}
```

There is only one "problem" within this code: as soon as a player reaches the number of points, it ends the game. It doesn't wait for the round to end..

Comment: playerArray[0].PlayerTurn = true bit at the top was a remnant of my previous failed attempt. I tried this out and It actually fixed the problem. I hope someone can offer me insight into where I went wrong with this. Thank you.

Comment: I'll update my question with the explanation about where you missed it..

Comment: Thank you for the updated explanation, now I see what went wrong. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

```
public void StartGame(int maxPoints)
    {
        //playerArray[0].PlayerTurn = true; // Is it necessary?

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Player currentPlayer = playerArray[i];
                currentPlayer.PlayerScore += rollAllDice();
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}': {1}", currentPlayer.PlayerName, currentPlayer.PlayerScore);

                if (currentPlayer.PlayerScore >= maxPoints)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, Player '{0}' has won by reaching {1} points.", currentPlayer.PlayerName, currentPlayer.PlayerScore);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your flow was just a little off, this may work better. To me the real issue was you should have rolled the dice first, then checked if it was a win. This would make your WHILE work properly.

```
public void StartGame(int maxPoints)
{
    while (!gameEnded)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.Length; i++)
        {
           playerArray[i].PlayerScore += rollAllDice();
           Console.WriteLine("'{0}': {1}", playerArray[i].PlayerName, playerArray[i].PlayerScore);

            if(playerArray[i].PlayerScore >= maxPoints){
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, Player '{0}' has won by reaching {1} points.",playerArray[i].PlayerName, playerArray[i].PlayerScore);
                gameEnded = true;
                break;
            }               
        }   
    }
}
```